# MongoDB: what is the better way to implement shared record with ability to remove it by each user

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB record, for example, called **Letter**.

This letter can be sent to some group of users, so many users have an access to it.

A **Letter** can be sent in a context of **Topic** that is shared between group of users.

So, the **Topic** model has the following structure:

- _id
- name (String)
- users_ids (Array of users ids, that can send letters withing this topic)

Also, each user can remove a letter for himself.

I have some concerns regarding how to implement/store this model with MongoDB.

**Variant 1:**

MongoDB record, fields:

- _id (ObjectId)
- topic_id (ObjectId)
- text (String)
- deleted_for_users_ids (Array)

When a user deletes a record then we add his ID to the **deleted_for_users_ids** array.

To retrieve records I use the following request:

```
db.letters.find({topic_id: 'X', deleted_for_users_ids: {$nin: 'user_id'}})
```

It's not good because we can't add an Index for 'nin' filter in MongoDB.

**Variant 2:**

MongoDB record, fields:

- _id (ObjectId)
- text (String)
- topic_id (ObjectId)
- accesible_for_users_ids (Array)

When a user creates a record then the **accesible_for_users_ids** array will be equal to the **topic.user_ids** array.

When a user deletes a record then we remove his ID to the **deleted_for_users_ids** array.

To retrieve records I use the following request:

```
db.letters.find({topic_id: 'X', accesible_for_users_ids: {$in: 'user_id'}})
```

It's better, now we can use Index because a filter 'in' can be covered by index.

But I see that indexes for array use a lot of RAM, which is not good.

====

So 2 concerns: RAM and speed.

Do you have any other ideas how to implement logic like that on MongoDB